# HTML and multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I have a web application in which I need to multiprocess a great deal of data. I have an application that runs well from the command line, however, when called from web page, it does not work. I have found numerous articles stating that pool.imap does not work with IDLE, only command line. Threading and Processes do not work, as they clog up the works. I have found only the pool.imap_unordered(target=processInfo, args=(stringdata,)) to work through the command line. My question is how web pages can call back end multiprocessing so that it works?
Thanks for any enlightenment.

Comment: What does "called from web page" mean? How does a web page call a Python app?

Comment: You might want to use a job broker like Celery http://www.celeryproject.org/ as a go-between.

Comment: yes, the web application is called by a Python application. It gathers all the information and then I need the backend to run processes. I will investigate celery project.

Comment: I was able to find a very simple solution. After using "import cgi, cgitb" to get the data from the web page, I used Python's subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) to start the Process module via the shell command. Works like a charm. I did not need mod_python or mod_wsgi or any interpreters/servers inside or beside Apache. Thanks for giving me ideas to investigate, which led me to the answer.